# Python/Scikit-learn/regressions - from pandas Dataframes to Scikit prediction

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have the following pandas DataFrame, called `main_frame`:

```
            target_var  input1  input2  input3  input4  input5    input6
Date
2013-09-01        13.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN   
2013-10-01        13.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN   
2013-11-01        12.2     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN   
2013-12-01        10.9     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN   
2014-01-01        11.7       0      13      42       0       0        16   
2014-02-01        12.0      13       8      58       0       0        14   
2014-03-01        12.8      13      15     100       0       0        24   
2014-04-01        13.1       0      11      50      34       0        18   
2014-05-01        12.2      12      14      56      30      71        18   
2014-06-01        11.7      13      16      43      44       0        22   
2014-07-01        11.2       0      19      45      35       0        18   
2014-08-01        11.4      12      16      37      31       0        24   
2014-09-01        10.9      14      14      47      30      56        20   
2014-10-01        10.5      15      17      54      24      56        22   
2014-11-01        10.7      12      18      60      41      63        21   
2014-12-01         9.6      12      14      42      29      53        16   
2015-01-01        10.2      10      16      37      31       0        20   
2015-02-01        10.7      11      20      39      28       0        19   
2015-03-01        10.9      10      17      75      27      87        22   
2015-04-01        10.8      14      17      73      30      43        25   
2015-05-01        10.2      10      17      55      31      52        24
```

I've been having trouble to explore the dataset on Scikit-learn and I'm not sure if the problem is the pandas Dataset, the dates as index, the NaN's/Infs/Zeros (which I don't know how to solve), everything, something else I wasn't able to track.

I want to build a simple regression to predict the next target_var item based on the variables named "Input" (1,2,3..).

Note that there are a lot of zeros and NaN's in the time series, and eventually we might find Inf's as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should first try to remove any row with a `Inf`, `-Inf` or NaN values (other methods include filling in the NaNs with, for example, the mean value of the feature).

```
df = df.replace(to_replace=[np.Inf, -np.Inf], value=np.NaN)
df = df.dropna()
```

Now, create a numpy matrix of you features and a vector of your targets. Given that your target variable is in the first column, you can use integer based indexing as follows:

```
X = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = df.iloc[:, 0].values
```

Then create and fit your model:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X=X, y=y)
```

Now you can observe your estimates:

```
>>> model.intercept_
12.109583092421092

>>> model.coef_
array([-0.05269033, -0.17723251,  0.03627883,  0.02219596, -0.01377465,
        0.0111017 ])
```

Comment: In the above example X=main_frame.input1[:,1:].values and y=main_frame.target_var[:,0].values, right?

Comment: `df` is just a generic term for dataframe.  You can replace it with `main_frame` in your case.  Use `iloc` (index location) instead of `input1` and `target_var`.

Comment: would you mind adding to your answer a way to plot it together with X and y?

Comment: 1) Only one question per post.  2) X is an array with 6 columns, what are you expecting?

Comment: Actually I'm having trouble to access the regression results along the time, to then plot it all together, but you are right, it was not part of the question. Thanks.

Comment: With your .intercept and .coef, is the formula always adding each coef? for example y = mx + b. Would the formula be y = -.0.05x + - 0.177x + 0.05x + 0.02x + -0.01x + 0.01x + 12.11? I am coming from minitab where it provides me with a formula which I can then use in Excel or wherever to predict future values. I just want to try to match this up with what I understand

Comment: @trench Yes, it would be `y = -.0.05input1 - 0.177input2 + 0.05input3 + 0.02input4 -0.01input5 + 0.01input6 + 12.11`